# Pdftotext - parse data from text file and export to mysql or json

Tags: sed, tr

I have hundreds of PDF files which I need to parse and insert into MySQL tables. I have converted a pdf file to text with pdftotext using -layout option. The data is voter information in the following format:

```
      1 TES1065268                                  2 TES1306415                                        3 AP281900579616
Elector's Name: DINESH ALAMPELLY              Elector's Name: DHURGA PRASAD E                     Elector's Name: KADARI JANGAIAH

Father's Name:   SRINIWASULU                  Father's Name:   BALAIAH E                          Father's Name:   RAMAIAH
                 ALAMPALLY
House No:        ---                          House No:        00                                 House No:        1-1
Age: 23       Sex: Male                       Age: 24       Sex: Male                             Age: 71       Sex: Male
     4 HCJ4116364                                  5 AP281900579174                                    6 AP281900582129
Elector's Name: Kadari Venkataiah             Elector's Name: KADARI RAAM SWAMI                   Elector's Name: Kadari Lakshmamma

Father's Name:   Jangaiah                     Father's Name:   JANGAIAH                           Husband's Name: Ramasvami

House No:        1-1                          House No:        1-1                                House No:        1-1
Age: 31       Sex: Male                       Age: 40       Sex: Male                             Age: 36       Sex: Female
           .                                             .                                                    .
           .                                             .                                                    .
           .                                             .                                                    .
           .                                             .                                                    .
```

I need to export this data into mysql table named "voters". Or is it easier to first convert this into JSON as there are colon separated data already?
I have tried using sed, tr column, fold but unable to reach a solution. Please help :)

Comment: This might help: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+bash+insert+mysql

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

Divide the file into 3, one for each column:

```
sed -rn -e 's/^(.{46})(.{52})/\1\n\2\n/;h;s/\n.*//w col1' -e 'g;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/w col2' -e 'g;s/.*\n//w col3' file
```

Collapse each record to a comma separated line:

```
sed -ri.bak 'N;N;N;N;s/^\s*(\S+)\s/\1,/;s/\n/,/g;s/\s*,[^:]*:\s*/,/g;s/\s*Sex:\s*(\S+)\s*/,\1/' col{1,2,3}
```

Interleave records in correct sequence using paste:

```
paste -d'\n' col{1,2,3} >csvFile
```

If you want headers use:

```
sed 'N;N;N;N;s/Sex:/\n&/;s/\n/,/g;s/^[^,]*/Rowid,Key/;s/:[^,]*//g;q' col1.bak >headers
sed -i.bak '1e cat headers' csvFile
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution, but somethings going wrong some where. I will try to improve on your solution.

Comment: Pls check the answer I have posted and kindly give your opinion

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would like to go about it:

1. Use grep (or any other command) to pick voter ids (1 TES1065268, in this the number 1 should be removed which can be done later). 
   a) To make this happen, append a keyword "voterid" in all the lines which have the voterids, then use grep to extract all these ids and print them in another file in a column and not row.
2. Use grep (or any other command) to match fields like Elector's Name: , Father's Name: etc and take the corresponding value and print in subsequent columns beside the voterid columns in new file.

This way we can get a neat column based data. But in some places in the text file, the name value is split into two lines. How to go about it?

Kindly someone provide me with additional inputs in this regard.